# All twelve the same

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

What is the phrase I'm looking for?

---

### (|X-)

```
                             A-Order
               
 |BKGS|XQYU|QZGU|QTMS|DCRH|  33141
 |DSBC|QBLS|YHPL|RHXP|AQPN|  32413 
 |RTEQ|YEVS|LMHR|IOPU|IMVB|  21342
 |HJOP|FRWA|AMLA|BONZ|TYVP|  23123  
 |QRWF|ZUFE|YUIS|WIUB|ARTO|  42212
```

Hint 1

> One letter per box.

Comment: This markdown confuses me on so many levels

Comment: @LukasRotter  Keep trying :) I'll add a hint tomorrow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is:

> MAGIC SQUARE
>  (a square containing a number of integers arranged so that the sum of the numbers is the same in each row, column, and 2 main diagonals, as alluded to by: | (vertical), X (diagonal), and - (horizontal) which are in the top parentheses.

We note that (as @new QOpenGLWidget posted) "A-Order" likely means

> "alphabetical order", and the digits matching the 5 columns with values from 1-4 suggest we take the nth item from each 4 digit value in the corresponding column.

This yields:

> |K|X|G|T|C|
>  |D|L|Y|H|P|
>  |Q|E|M|U|I|
>  |J|R|A|N|V|
>  |W|F|S|B|O|

> Converting to numbers yields:
> 11 24 7  20 3
> 4  12 25 8  16
> 17 5  13 21 9
> 10 18 1  14 22
> 23 6  19 2  15

> Which is a MAGIC SQUARE where each row, column, and diagonal sum to 65. (12 sums in total, so "All twelve the same" as stated in the title!).

Comment: Nice solve and well-explained.

Comment: That's the phrase I was looking for and everything explained correctly. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer.

"A-Order" seems to mean alphabetical order, so let's order our words in alphabetical order.

```
|BGKS|QUXY|GQUZ|MQST|CDHR| 33141
|BCDS|BLQS|HLPY|HPRX|ANPQ| 32413
|EQRT|ESVY|HLMR|IOPU|BIMV| 21342
|HJOP|AFRW|AALM|BNOZ|PTVY| 23123
|FQRW|EFUZ|ISUY|BIUW|AORT| 42212
```

Now use the numbers on the right. So we get

```
|K|X|G|T|C|
|C|L|S|H|N|
|Q|E|M|U|I|
|J|R|A|N|V|
|W|F|S|B|O|
```

...which, unfortunately, doesn't have anything too useful. I've tried a Caesar cipher, but it doesn't work. I'm thinking about trying a Caesar cipher on the box, then doing the steps above.

I also don't know how (|X-) or "All twelve the same" figures into this.

Comment: You got the right the idea. But check row two again (some errors). I made an error myself, fixed now.